# Перенос текста в HTML ломает структуру

Tags: html, css, текст, span

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, у меня есть див, внутри которого table-cell элементы (необходимо чтобы текст выровнялся по центру, иначе никак). При этом необходимо чтобы длина ячейки не была больше 180 пикселей. В итоге, из-за автоматического переноса текста, как я понимаю, появляется мнимый тег 
 или что-то вроде (зависящее от размера текста), который переносит все последующие элементы. Как это пофиксить?

```
<div>
        <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 25px;">Небольшой текст</span></div>
            <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 30px;">Текст</span></div>
            <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 22px;">Очень длинный текст, который сломает мне всю структуру</span></div>
            <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 20px;">Не такой длинный текст, но все равно беда</span></div>
    </div>
```

И CSS

```
.cell {
padding-right: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
border: 6px solid black;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
font-family: Arial;
width: auto;
height: 100px;
max-width: 180px;
display: inline-table;
cursor: pointer;
word-wrap: normal;
word-break: normal;
}

span {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Ну в тему, но... можно вообще убрать все onclick и в скрипте записать `let cell = document.querySelectorAll('.cell'); for( let i = 0; i < cell.length; i++ ){ cell[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ settext(this); }); }`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.d{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cell {
padding-right: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
border: 6px solid black;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
font-family: Arial;
/*width: auto;*/
height: 100px;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
-ms-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
width: 180px;
/*max-width: 180px;*/
/*display: inline-table;*/
cursor: pointer;
/*word-wrap: normal;
word-break: normal;*/
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}

span {
  /*display: table-cell;*/
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  /*width: 180px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
    <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 25px;">Небольшой текст</span></div>
    <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 30px;">Текст</span></div>
    <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 22px;">Очень длинный текст, который сломает мне всю структуру</span></div>
    <div class="cell" onclick="settext(this)"><span style="font-size: 20px;">Не такой длинный текст, но все равно беда</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Флекс родительскому диву можно добавить? Если да, то так (класс прописать у дива):

```
.my-div-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Строка уже не прыгает, но требует еще каких-то дополнительных решений.